# Angular 14 .browserslistrc and polyfills

Tags: angular, angular-cli, polyfills, angular14, browserslist

I am looking for polyfill loading mechanism as webpack do with babel for Angular. I am still using Angular 14. I use string replaceAll in my ts code. Add chrome 70 in the .browserslistrc and hope to see related polyfill in dist file. But it does not care about. Note: Syntax converting work like array function to normal function.